# MySQL force variable to recalculate

Tags: mysql, variables, mariadb

I'm using MySQL's event scheduler to execute code at regular intervals i.e. every day or every hour. Within my code I use 'CURDATE()' and I assign this to a variable. Unfortunately, MySQL calculates this in the first instance only. It does not recalculate it within each iteration, meaning the first time through it will have the correct date but every time after that it will have the wrong date. The same also occurs if I run the code manually i.e. without the event scheduler.

How can I force MySQL to re-calculate variables?

I've tried this (this one works the first time only):

```
SET @stmt := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myColum_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%M_%D_%H_%m'), ' SMALLINT(5);');
PREPARE stmt from @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

And this (this one doesn't even work the first time):

```
PREPARE stmt from ALTER TABLE myTable ADD
CONCAT('myColumn_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%M_%D_%H_%mm'), '
SMALLINT(5);'); EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: if you want `CURDATE()` to always fetch latest value than you should simply replace variable usage with `CURDATE()` itself which will make it always fetch latest value.

Comment: SET @stmt := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD column_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%M_%D_%H_%m'), ' SMALLINT(5);');
PREPARE stmt from @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;

Comment: I can't find how to do what I want it to without using a variable

Comment: can you update question to include complete code snippet, would be easier to help that way.

Comment: ':=' seems redundant in this context. Surely '=' would suffice.

Comment: whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two issues `NOW()` returns the time at the start of the connection regardless how many statements are executed. `CURDATE()` will always be current however.

The syntax in [ALTER TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/) can't take arbitrary expressions.

What you can do is use  [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myColum_',
         DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y_%M_%D_%H_%m'),
         ' SMALLINT(5);')
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm using version 5.2 so I figure that's why

Comment: You can use `CURDATE()` in your prepared statements. As a general rule if you use something really old and unsupported you probably should mention it's version in your question. Above applies to 10.2, the lowest stable GA series at the time of answering.

Comment: Is it really unsupported? I didn't realise that. So basically I need to change my entire operating system just to update a variable?

Comment: Where does it say it's unsupported and unsupported to what exactly?

Comment: Is there no other way to achieve this? It doesn't necessarily have to be a date. It could just be a different value. I just need it so that every time the event runs, a different title is given to the new column.

Comment: @Norma You'll find a list of MariaDB versions [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server/). Click through to the version you have and you'll find that v5.2 was released over eight years ago. Unsupported means no bug fixes, no security fixes, no new features. If something doesn't work, you're on your own. You should upgrade as a matter of course as each new stable release emerges.